# in grails when i am selecting status from the list of statuses i could not get the status value for the corresponding id from generic_status table

Tags: grails

```
 <g:applyLayout name="form/select">
  <content tag="label"><g:message code="New Status"/>:</content>
       <content tag="label.for">toStatus</content>

 <g:select name="toStatus" from="${statuses}"
         noSelection="['': message(code: 'Voucher.status.type')]"
                      optionKey="id" optionValue="description"
                      value="statusValue"/>
                </g:applyLayout>
```

here i want to get the selected status but i got error as status_id couldnot be null
the corresponding table
id status_value
52 1
53 2
54 3
55 4
56 5
here 1,2,3,4,5 are the statuses i want to update that status

Comment: def statusupdate = {VoucherWS voucherWS = webServicesSession.getVoucherWS(params.int('id'))
   
   VoucherDTO voucherDTO=new VoucherDAS().find(voucherWS.getId());
   Integer status =Integer.valueOf(params.toStatus);
   VoucherStatusDTO voucherStatus=new VoucherStatusDAS().find(status); here i am getting the error as status_id could not be null

Comment: What is the contents of the `statuses` collection used in the from for the select?

Comment: Also is VoucherStatusDAS a Grails domain class?

Comment: statuses=new VoucherStatusDAS().findAll() from this we can get list of statuses

Comment: i want that should be a type of VoucherStatusDTO